# A Double Click event also triggers Click event in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

**Adding Event Listener**

```
function Solitaire() {
    this.table.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
    this.table.addEventListener("dblclick", this.handleDoubleClick.bind(this));
}
```

**Handling Event**

```
Solitaire.prototype.handleDoubleClick = function(event) {
   console.log("DoubleClick");
};
Solitaire.prototype.handleClick = function(event) {
   console.log("Click");
};
```

**Expected output (in console) on a double click event**

```
DoubleClick
```

**But the output I get in console:**

```
Click
Click
DoubleClick
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about easeljs, but I can tell you about how it is done in jQuery, where you need to "hack" it to make it actually work.

```
var DELAY = 500;
$('#my_element').on('click', function(e){

++clicks; // Count the clicks

if(clicks === 1){
// One click has been made

var myTimerToDetectDoubleClick = setTimeout(function(){

console.log('This was a single click');
doStuffForSingleClick();
clicks = 0;
}, DELAY);

} // End of if
else{

// Someone is clicking pretty damn fast, they probably mean double click :p
clearTimeout(myTimerToDetectDoubleClick);
doStuffForDoubleClick();
clicks = 0;
}
}).on('dblclick', function(evt){

evt.preventDefault(); // cancel system's default double click
});
```

The basic essence will remain the same for event handling for easeljs. You can imitate this behaviour accordingly there.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It didn't work out. I set some flag. once first click is triggered, the flag will be true. logic will be executed if the flag is false. No luck since the script execution speed is slower than event trigger.